# UTC address in MEW -

Tags: myetherwallet

I am new to all this. I didn't know that MEW could not access my password protected excel file! I deleted my UTC address because didn't like it sitting there in my folders in WINDOWS 10 FILE EXPLORER. So now I cannot repaste the UTC address in any folder. Does anyone know how to save it again  in my folder? It has an 890z extension. Thanks! somehow in my searching i came across a manual for it but now i cannot find that info. Appreciate any help here! THanks!!

Comment: Have you cleaned the recycle bin? You could restore the file from there.

Comment: @Grace UTC file in a folder are ok if you use a strong password, since they are encrypted. How did you insert your UTC file into an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I deleted in recycle! also!! just copy pasted into excel. But i cannot use the utc address though ...or can i?? how?? i can only use the private encrypted one. It only allows uploading for UTC keystore address! it cannot access my excel file that way. Any other choices??

Comment: @Grace I tried to copy+past an UTC file from Explorer to Excel, but it didn't let me do that. Are you using a plugin? How do you generate the 890z file extension? How does it shows in Excel? Does it shows as a file or as a text in a cell? If you double click in it inside Excel does something happen?

Comment: just copy paste worked for me for excel. MEW generated the extension when you downloaded it the first time. Too bad they won't let you do it again! shows up only as a text in Excel i guess.  When i tried to double click the UTC address before i deleted it a box showed up asking which app to open it with and there was an APP called 890z!!! WE NEED MORE INFO ON THAT APP!!! but i dont' know how to get it back and can't get anything in GOOGLE. DO YOU HAVE THE UTC code? Try double clicking it and find that app?

Comment: I found another UTC address!!!

Comment: Can anyone help me, my problem is about wallet in MyEtherWallet, I have lost the private key but I have its UTC how to restore my private key by using UTC !!!!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19109)